# eBPF: Properly passing fixed length strings from userspace using eBPF array maps

Tags: ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf, libbpf

I have a BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY map that stores instances of this struct:

```
    struct target_d_name {
        unsigned long int len;
        char name[PID_LEN_MAX]; //PID_LEN_MAX = 8, it is a macro
    };
```

Here is the map definition:

```
    struct {
        __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
        __uint(max_entries, 8);
        __type(key, u32);
        __type(value, sizeof(struct target_d_name));
    } map_d_name_tgts SEC(".maps");
```

What I am doing can be summarised as the following:

1. Hook exit of getents64
2. Loop through all dirent64 structures being returned
3. See if any of `dirent64->d_name` strings match anything in `target_d_name->name`

Here is the code that does the actual string comparison between the dirent64 strings and the strings in my map:

```
    //iterator_limit is either len(filename) or PID_LEN_MAX, whichever is smallest
    for (k = 0; k < iterator_limit; ++k) {
      if (filename[k] != target_d_name_instance->name[k]) break;
    }
```

As you can see, everything is in bounds. However at load time the eBPF verifier errors out with:

```
    invalid access to map value, value_size=8 off=8 size=1
    R5 min value is outside of the allowed memory range
```

Where R5 attempts to dereference the address of `target_d_name_instance->name[k]`.

At first I expected this to work since everything is in bounds. Upon further investigation however I found numerous other people who have come across this problem. Namely:

- [eBPF: invalid access to map value even with bounds check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74178703/ebpf-invalid-access-to-map-value-even-with-bounds-check)
- https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/3269
- https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/f9c2ab1f-42a9-f5eb-f9bf-63402c6a8a62@uliege.be/T/

From these links I gathered that the eBPF verifier fails to keep track of the size of the character buffers in my struct. As such, when I iterate with 0 <= k <= PID_LEN_MAX, at some point k may fall outside the allowed memory range. While this is impossible, the eBPF verifier isn't aware of this.

**However I still don't know how what my new approach should be. How else can I pass strings to my eBPF programs from userspace?** What if I need to carry out string comparisons on them and hence iterate over them? I noticed the existence of the `bpf_strncmp()` helper, but it only works on constants and is therefore not very useful if the strings are being dynamically generated.

UPDATE:

Here is a minimal example that produces an identical error:

```
    u32 index = 0;
    struct target_d_name * current_d_name 
        = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&map_d_name_tgts, &index);
    if (current_d_name == 0) return -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < PID_LEN_MAX; ++i) {
        current_d_name->name[i] = 'u';
    }
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about change

```
    struct {
        __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
        __uint(max_entries, 8);
        __type(key, u32);
        __type(value, sizeof(struct target_d_name));
    } map_d_name_tgts SEC(".maps");
```

to

```
    struct {
        __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
        __uint(max_entries, 8);
        __type(key, u32);
        __type(value, struct target_d_name);  // changed
    } map_d_name_tgts SEC(".maps");
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. I see I was actually allocating size_t worth of bytes.